# how to make block diagram of ul and li in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make block diagram of ul and li in jquery ? I found one solution And modified it and get the exact result what i want .
http://jsfiddle.net/5wSc5/
or

In this example there is nested ul and li with anchor tags .It show sow block diagram of that.

But I apply this concept in another example (having ul and li but no anchor tag) .it fail to make block .I remove all anchor tag from css.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9Pb/
can you please tell where I am wrong .?

```
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li :hover, .tree li :hover+ul li  {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li :hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li :hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li :hover+ul::before, 
.tree li :hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Comment: Can you just replace the anchor with a span: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5wSc5/1/?

Comment: @ezanker actually requirement is that we have only ul and li no anchor or span

Comment: @ezanker I want to make block view of this tree view http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/96/.I used jstree to make tree view.I used this api http://www.jstree.com/api/

Comment: @ezanker do you have any idea ?

Comment: @user3703527 - I think that's gonna be very hard.. I see you changed hte `.tree li a{` at the end of the CSS to `.tree li{`, but what you may or may not have missed is that there already is a `.tree li{` earlier in the CSS. Both elements have their own rules, if you're gonna combine those that's just asking for trouble. You're probably gonna have to do god knows what to make this work, if it's possible at all... I would stick with the working example, if you don't want `a href` go with the `span` provided by @ezanker, what's wrong with a span?

Comment: @myfunkyside As I said I wait to show block diagram of this tree view jsfiddle.net/fuu94/96/.I used jstree to make tree view.I used this api jstree.com/api

Comment: is there any plugin available which make diagram of nested ul and li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am wrong But when You apply same CSS it will make block diagram.Because Internally it make anchor tag in jstree.Please inspect your HTML then you find that.